# Powermockito spy and Kotlin's object declarations: Cannot subclass final class

Tags: java, mockito, kotlin, powermock, powermockito

I have some problems with object declarations in Koltin and Powermocks' spy() when converting tests from java to kotlin

```
open class TestData(val test: String){
    open fun test(){
        println("TestData")
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
open class MockitoTests {

    lateinit var testData: TestData
    lateinit var testDataObjectDeclaration: TestData

    @Before
    open fun setup(){
        testData = PowerMockito.spy(TestData("Test"))
        testDataObjectDeclaration = PowerMockito.spy(object: TestData("test"){
            override fun test() {}
        })
    }

    @Test
    fun dummyTest() {}
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class at.lukle.kotlinplayground.MockitoTests$setup$1

```
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:447)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:124)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:58)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:121)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:69)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy(PowerMockito.java:221)
at at.lukle.kotlinplayground.MockitoTests.setup(MockitoTests.kt:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

The according Java Test runs just fine: 
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MockitoJavaTest {

```
private TestData testData;
private TestData testDataAnnonymousClass;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    testData = spy(new TestData("test"));
    testDataAnnonymousClass = spy(new TestData("test"){
        @Override
        public void test() {

        }
    });
}

@Test
public void dummyTest(){

}
```

}`

Why does it work with Java's Annonymous class but not with Kotlin's Object Declarations?

When I decompile the generated Bytecode of the Kotlin Test, the outcome is almost the same as the Java Test:

`Object var10001 = PowerMockito.spy(new TestData("Test"));
     Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(var10001, 
     "PowerMockito.spy(TestData(\"Test\"))");
     this.testData = (TestData)var10001;
     var10001 = PowerMockito.spy(new TestData("test") {
         public void test() {}
     });`